# Попиксельное сравнение двух картинок

Tags: java

```
package com.company.MyFirstProgect;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\kuhaj\\Downloads\\image1.png");
        File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\kuhaj\\Downloads\\image2.png");

        BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(file);
        BufferedImage image2 = ImageIO.read(file1);

        int columns = image1.getWidth();
        int rows = image1.getHeight();

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; rows++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
                int rgb = image1.getRGB(col, row);
                int rgb2 = image2.getRGB(col, row);

                if (rgb != rgb2){
                    System.out.println("NO!!!!!");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Когда `image1` и `image2` разные, этот код все равно считает их одинаковыми и не выводит `NO!!!!!` В чем проблема?

Comment: И в чем тут проблема? Пожалуйста опишите что конкретно не работает.

Comment: Не сравнивает картинки они одинаковы! Но на самом деле они разные!

Comment: Как минимум нужно сравнить размеры первой и второй картинки, у вас сейчас получается что если первая картинка 10 на 10, то а вторая 1000 на 1000, то сравнивается только кусочек от первой картинки

Comment: Чучуть не понял в чем проблема

Comment: Получается я условие не верно построил?

Comment: Почему не имеет как раз при таком сравнении маленькая первая картинка может посчитаться равной большой (например, если маленькая это обрезанная часть большой)

Comment: @AlexanderKukhtin у вас, кстати, в вопросе `rows++`, а должно быть `row++`

Comment: @Regent, да похоже основная проблема была именно в rows++

Comment: @Regent Спасибо!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Для сравнения любых объектов первое что нужно сделать это сравнить размер объектов.

```
if (image1.getWidth() != image2.getWidth() || image1.getHeight() != image2.getHeight()){
      System.out.println("NO!!!!!");
      return;
}
```

Иначе если первая картинка 1 на 1 пиксель, то вы сравните первый пиксель из второй картинки и если он совпадет, то считаете картинки одинаковыми, даже если вторая картинка намного больше.

**P.S.** Так же в комментариях вам написали, что вместо

```
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; rows++) {
```

должно быть

```
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
```

При rows++ у вас сравнивается только row = 0 (нулевой ряд все колонки), потом доходит до переполнения int и выходит.

Comment: Nfr Так затем нужно задействовать переменные

Comment: Да, пардон, автор плохо сформулировал предложения - не осознал сразу

Comment: Извиняюсь, есть 2 картинки они идентичны но на 2й картинке есть надпись , которой нет на первой картинке, но почему условие показывает что они одинаковы?