# Как сравнить изображения на java?

Tags: java, изображения, bufferedimage

Есть ли встроенные методы, позволяющие сравнить изображения на полное сходство (Не просто == или img.equals(img2), ибо в первом это разные объекты, а второе в классе BufferedImage не реализовано и остается простым ==)?

Comment: Я понимаю,что это не встроенный метод,но можно сравнить массив байтов двух фотографий вручную

Comment: Сделал, работает

Answer (score 3):

**Способ 1.** Можете конвертировать изображения в массивы байтов и сравнить.

**Способ 2** Сравнить попиксельно, через двумерный массив, как сделано тут:
[*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744478/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA)

**Способ 3** Воспользуйтесь нейросетью, что будет сравнивать изображения. Из плюсов можно отметить, что если сделать две фотографии на одном и том же месте, то они почти всегда будут формально "разными", поэтому предыдущие два способа не будут их отличать.

Если вам нужно проверить полностью ли одинаковы изображения, то используйте 1-ый и 2-ой способы, а если вам нужно проверить одинаково ли то, что находится на изображении, то используйте третий способ.

P.S Насколько я полагаю Вам нужны первые два способа, но вывод выше нужен для тех, кто будет читать эту тему.